# Paint on Image MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Basically, I have a matrix filled with 0's and 1's that is a representation of an image. I essentially want a GUI that allows me to arbitrarily draw or make lines on the image, so essentially, Microsoft paint capabilities of drawing on the image.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Have you tried [ginput](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you can use [`ginput`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html).

Here is a short program you can test.

```
fh = figure;
imageh = imshow(false(50));

% Create a button in the figure.
uicontrol('Parent',fh,'Style','pushbutton','String','paint','Callback',{@paintButtonCallback, imageh});


% button callback function
function paintButtonCallback(~,~,imageh)
[x,y] = ginput(1);

% round the values so they can be used for indexing.
x = round(x);
y = round(y);

% make sure the values do not go outside the image.
s = size(imageh.CData);
if x > s(2) || y > s(1) || x < 1 || y < 1
    return
end

% make the selected pixel white.
imageh.CData(round(y),round(x)) = true;
end
```

---

## Update

I'm not sure if there is any existing toolbox would allow you to edit images as conveniently as you can with MS paint. However, it is possible to code it yourselves.

To draw a line you can use 'ginput(2)' to take two points and plot the line. Note that the `findLine` function isn't perfect.

```
[x,y] = ginput(2);

% find all pixels on the line xy
ind = findLine(size(imageh.CData),x,y);

% make the selected pixel white.
imageh.CData(ind) = true;

function [x,y] = findLine(x,y)
% Find all pixels that lie between points defined by [x(1),y(1)] and [x(2),y(2)].

supersampling = 1.2;
[x,y,~] = improfile(s,round(x),round(y),max([diff(x);diff(y)])*supersampling);
ind = sub2ind(s,round(x),round(y));
end
```

If you have Image Processing Toolbox, you have the option to use `drawline`, which gives a better draw experience and you can get the pixels on the line using `createMask` function:

```
h = drawline;
ind = h.createMask;
```

`drawfreehand` may be also relevant:

```
h = drawfreehand;
x = h.Position(:,1);
y = h.Position(:,2);
```

You can delete the object created on the image with `delete(h)` if you don't need it. See more similar functions in [MATLAB documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/roi-based-processing.html).

It is also painful when you have to click the paint button each time you need to paint a point. To overcome this problem, you can use the `ButtonDownFcn` of the figure. The paint button will update the `ButtonDownFcn` with a meaningful callback or empty value depending on the circumstance:

```
function paintButtonCallback(obj,~,imageh)
if isempty(obj.Tag)
    imageh.ButtonDownFcn = @paintMode;
    obj.Tag = 'on';
else
    imageh.ButtonDownFcn = '';
    obj.Tag = '';
end
```

And the meaningful callback `paintMode`:

```
function paintMode(~,~)
    [x,y] = ginput(1);

    % round the values so they can be used for indexing.
    x = round(x);
    y = round(y);

    % make sure the values do not go outside the image.
    s = size(imageh.CData);
    if x > s(2) || y > s(1) || x < 1 || y < 1
        return
    end

    % make the selected pixel white.
    imageh.CData(y,x) = true;
end
```

The full demo code:

```
fh = figure;
imageh = imshow(false(20));

% Create buttons in the figure.
uicontrol('Parent',fh,'Style','pushbutton','String','paint','Callback',{@paintButtonCallback, imageh});
bh = uicontrol('Parent',fh,'Style','pushbutton','String','line','Callback',{@lineButtonCallback, imageh});
bh.Position(2) = 50;
bh2 = uicontrol('Parent',fh,'Style','pushbutton','String','line2','Callback',{@line2ButtonCallback, imageh});
bh2.Position(2) = 80;
bh3 = uicontrol('Parent',fh,'Style','pushbutton','String','free','Callback',{@freeButtonCallback, imageh});
bh3.Position(2) = 110;

% button callback function
function paintButtonCallback(obj,~,imageh)
if isempty(obj.Tag)
    imageh.ButtonDownFcn = @paintMode;
    obj.Tag = 'on';
else
    imageh.ButtonDownFcn = '';
    obj.Tag = '';
end

    function paintMode(~,~)
        [x,y] = ginput(1);

        % round the values so they can be used for indexing.
        x = round(x);
        y = round(y);

        % make sure the values do not go outside the image.
        s = size(imageh.CData);
        if x > s(2) || y > s(1) || x < 1 || y < 1
            return
        end

        % make the selected pixel white.
        imageh.CData(y,x) = true;
    end
end

% button callback function
function lineButtonCallback(~,~,imageh)
% take two points at a time
[x,y] = ginput(2);

% make sure the values do not go outside the image.
s = size(imageh.CData);
if any(x > s(2)+0.5 | y > s(1)+0.5 | x < 0.5 | y < 0.5) || (diff(x) == 0 && diff(y) == 0)
    return
end

% find all pixels on the line xy
ind = findLine(size(imageh.CData),x,y);

% make the selected pixel white.
imageh.CData(ind) = true;
end

function ind = findLine(s,x,y)
% Find all pixels that lie between points defined by [x(1),y(1)] and [x(2),y(2)].

supersampling = 1.2;
[x,y,~] = improfile(s,round(x),round(y),max([diff(x);diff(y)])*supersampling);
ind = sub2ind(s,round(x),round(y));
end

% button callback function
function line2ButtonCallback(~,~,imageh)
% take two points at a time
h = drawline;
ind = h.createMask;
delete(h);

% make the selected pixel white.
imageh.CData(ind) = true;
end

% button callback function
function freeButtonCallback(~,~,imageh)
% take two points at a time
h = drawfreehand;
x = h.Position(:,1);
y = h.Position(:,2);
delete(h);

ind = sub2ind(size(imageh.CData),round(y),round(x));

% make the selected pixel white.
imageh.CData(ind) = true;
end
```

Comment: So this isn't exactly what I am looking for, but it is a step in the right direction. I was basically just wondering if there was anything in MATLAB or an add-on that essentially lets me microsoft paint images as I will likely be adding a lot of lines to a lot of images and editing pixels them one-by-one is less than ideal (although your solution is better than keeping track of individual pixels and doing it manually.

Comment: @jshackle I also suggest you to update your question as you did not mention the need of adding lines in the image.